# DENSE_RANK() without duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, dense-rank

Here's what my data looks like:

```
| col1 | col2 | denserank | whatiwant |
|------|------|-----------|-----------|
| 1    | 1    | 1         | 1         |
| 2    | 1    | 1         | 1         |
| 3    | 2    | 2         | 2         |
| 4    | 2    | 2         | 2         |
| 5    | 1    | 1         | 3         |
| 6    | 2    | 2         | 4         |
| 7    | 2    | 2         | 4         |
| 8    | 3    | 3         | 5         |
```

Here's the query I have so far:

```
SELECT col1, col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COL2) AS [denserank]
FROM [table1]
ORDER BY [col1] asc
```

What I'd like to achieve is for my denserank column to **increment** every time there is a change in the value of col2 (even if the value itself is reused). I can't actually order by the column I have denserank on, so that won't work). See the `whatiwant` column for an example.

Is there any way to achieve this with `DENSE_RANK()`? Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using window functions:

```
with t(col1  ,col2) as (
select 1 , 1 union all  
select 2 , 1 union all  
select 3 , 2 union all  
select 4 , 2 union all  
select 5 , 1 union all  
select 6 , 2 union all  
select 7 , 2 union all  
select 8 , 3
)
select t.col1,
    t.col2,
    sum(x) over (
        order by col1
        ) whatyouwant
from (
    select t.*,
        case 
            when col2 = lag(col2) over (
                    order by col1
                    )
                then 0
            else 1
            end x
    from t
    ) t
order by col1;
```

Produces:

[image]

It does a single table read and forms group of consecutive equal col2 values in increasing order of col1 and then finds dense rank on that.

- `x`: Assign value 0 if previous row's col2 is same as this row's col2 (in order of increasing `col1`) otherwise 1
- `whatyouwant`: create groups of equal values of `col2` in order of increasing `col1` by doing an incremental sum of the value `x` generated in the last step and that's your output.

Comment: You just replicated my code in different way thats not fair. Previously you code was so different

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with a recursive cte like this:

```
declare @Dept table (col1 integer, col2 integer)

insert into @Dept values(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 2),(4, 2),(5, 1),(6, 2),(7, 2),(8, 3)

;with a as (
select col1, col2, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1) as rn
from @Dept),
s as 
(select col1, col2, rn, 1 as dr from a where rn=1
union all
select a.col1, a.col2, a.rn, case when a.col2=s.col2 then s.dr else s.dr+1 end as dr 
from a inner join s on a.rn=s.rn+1)
col1, col2, dr from s

result:

col1        col2        dr
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           1
3           2           2
4           2           2
5           1           3
6           2           4
7           2           4
8           3           5
```

The ROW_NUMBER is only required in case your col1 values are not sequential. If they are you can use the recursive cte straight away

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `SUM OVER(Order by)` window aggregate function

```
SELECT col1,Col2,
       Sum(CASE WHEN a.prev_val = a.col2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS whatiwant 
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               Lag(col2, 1)OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS prev_val
        FROM   Yourtable) a
ORDER  BY col1;
```

**How it works:**

`LAG` window function is used to find the previous `col2` for each row ordered by `col1`

`SUM OVER(Order by)` will increment the number only when previous `col2` is not equal to current `col2`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible in pure SQL using some gaps and islands tricks, but the path of least resistance might be to use a session variable combined with `LAG()` to keep track of when your computed dense rank changes value.  In the query below, I use `@a` to keep track of the change in the dense rank, and when it changes this variable is incremented by 1.

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 1
SELECT t.col1,
       t.col2,
       t.denserank,
       @a = CASE WHEN LAG(t.denserank, 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t.col1) = t.denserank
                 THEN @a
                 ELSE @a+1 END AS [whatiwant]
FROM
(
    SELECT col1, col2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COL2) AS [denserank]
    FROM [table1]
) t
ORDER BY t.col1
```